# Qualitative difference between "continuous" and "discontinuous" states on $M(G)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, measure-theory, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $G$ be a locally compact Abelian group (we can think that $G={\mathbb R}$). Let $C_0(G)$ be the space of continuous functions $u:G\to{\mathbb C}$ [vanishing at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanish_at_infinity) with the usual $\sup$-norm, and $M(G)$ the space of [complex Radon measures](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Real+Analysis%3A+Modern+Techniques+and+Their+Applications%2C+2nd+Edition-p-9780471317166) on $G$, understood as a Banach space dual to the Banach space $C_0(G)$:
$$
M(G)=C_0(M)^*.
$$
The Banach space $M(G)$ is naturally endowed with the structure of a Banach algebra with the convolution of measures as the multiplication
$$
\alpha * \beta,\qquad \alpha,\beta\in M(G),
$$
and, moreover, it also has a natural involution:
$$
\alpha^\bullet(u)=\overline{\alpha(\overline{\widetilde{u}})},\qquad \alpha\in M(G),\quad u\in C_0(G),
$$
where $\overline{z}$ is the usual involition of the complex number $z\in{\mathbb C}$, and $\widetilde{u}$ is the antipode of the function $u\in C_0(G)$:
$$
\widetilde{u}(t)=u(t^{-1}),\qquad t\in G.
$$

So $M(G)$ is a *Banach algebra with involution*. And formally we can define *states* on $M(G)$, as linear continuous functionals $\sigma:M(G)\to{\mathbb C}$ with the properties
$$
\sigma(\alpha^\bullet*\alpha)\ge 0, \qquad \sigma(\delta^e)=1,\qquad \alpha\in M(G),
$$
where $e\in G$ is the unit in $G$ and $\delta^e$ is the delta-measure supported in $e$.

It is more or less obvious, that each normalized *continuous* [positive-definite function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function_on_a_group) $f:G\to{\mathbb C}$ defines a state on $M(G)$ by the formula
$$
\sigma(\alpha)=\int_G f(t)\ \alpha(d t) \tag{1}
$$
and by the [Bochner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem), we can represent the action of $\sigma$ as the integral by some positive measure $\mu$ on the Pontryagin dual group $\widehat{G}$:
$$
\sigma(\alpha)=\int_{\widehat{G}} {\mathcal F}(\alpha)(\chi)\ \mu(d\chi) \tag{2}
$$
where
$$
{\mathcal F}(\alpha)(\chi)=\int_G \chi(t)\ \alpha(d t),\qquad \chi\in\widehat{G}
$$
is the Fourier transform of the measure $\alpha$.

I would call such states $\sigma$ on $M(G)$ *"regular states"*, since intuitively they are what we expect them to be.

But strange thing, there are some other, *"irregular states"* on $M(G)$. Namely, the function
$$
f(t)=\begin{cases}1, & t=e\\ 0, & t\ne e\end{cases}
$$
(where $e\in G$ is the unit of the group $G$) gives another state by the same formula (1), which can be simplified in this case as follows:
$$
\sigma(\alpha)=\int_G f(t)\ \alpha(d t)=\alpha(\{e\}). \tag{3}
$$
And if $G$ is not discrete, then $f$ cannot be a continuous function on $G$, and in this case the state (3) cannot be represented in the form (2) (i.e., as an integral of the Fourier transform by some measure $\mu\ge 0$ on $\widehat{G}$).

And I deduce from this that there is a qualitative difference between the states on $M(G)$, which can be represented in the form (2) and those that cannot. My question is

> what is this qualitative difference between the states (2) and (3) in terms of the properties of $M(G)$ considering it as the Banach algebra with involution?

In other words if we have a state $\sigma:M(G)\to{\mathbb C}$, do we have a possibility to understand if it can be represented in the form (2) if we look only at the properties of $\sigma$ as a functional on $M(G)$? (We can't restore the topology of $G$ from $M(G)$, so our answer can't be like "$\sigma$ must be generated by some continuous positive-definite function $f$". Equally, we can't say "$\sigma$ must be $C_0(G)$-weakly continuous", because we can't restore $C_0(G)$ from $M(G)$.)

My conjecture is that perhaps the difference between (2) and (3) is that these states relate differently to the monotonicity conditions. Using the [Beppo Levi lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Beppo_Levi%27s_lemma) one can show that if a sequence of measures $\alpha_n\in M(G)$ tends to a measure $\alpha\in M(G)$ monotonously with respect to the *preorder on $M(G)$ generated by the involution*,
$$
0\le\alpha_1\le\alpha_2\le...\le\alpha_n\le...\le\sup_n\alpha_n=\alpha
$$
then the values of the state $\sigma$ of the form (2) tend to what we need:
$$
\sigma(\alpha_n)\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\sigma(\alpha) \tag{4}
$$
But if we consider the state $\sigma$ of the form (3), we cannot use the Bochner theorem, cannot represent $\sigma$ in the form (2), and because of that I am not sure that this state satisfies the condition (4). So a simplified version of my question is the following:

> is the state $\sigma$ of the form (3) on $M(G)$ monotone in the sense that it preserves the monotonous convergence of sequences?

I think this must be simple, but I stuck in this, and if somebody could clarify this to me, I would be very grateful.

P.S. Excuse me, I understood that the state (3) satisfies (4), because this functional acts only on the discrete part $\alpha^d$ of the measure $\alpha$
$$
\sigma(\alpha)=\sigma(\alpha^d)
$$
and this means that we can consider the discrete topology on the group $G$, and with this topology $G$ becomes again a locally compact Abelian group $G^d$, and $\sigma$ can be considered as a state on the algebra $M(G^d)$, and we again can apply the Bochner theorem.

So my conjecture was wrong, I am sorry. However, the initial (main) question remains open: if somebody could explain how to separate "regular states" from "irregular" using only the properties of $M(G)$, that would be great.

Comment: I suspect your "regular" means "weak* continuous" and "irregular" means "not weak* continuous".

Comment: @NikWeaver but what is "weak*", if we don't know how to restore $C_0(G)$?

Comment: Weak* relative to the duality pairing between $C_0(G)$ and $M(G)$.

Comment: @NikWeaver the question is how to separate "good" states from "bad" states without $C_0(G)$. It is supposed that we know only the properties of $M(G)$ as a Banach algebra with involution, we don't know that it has a predual space and we can't restore this predual (unless you can suggest a construction that recovers $C_0(G)$ from $M(G)$).

Answer (score 2):

Your definition (2) explicitly uses the Fourier transform, so let's think about this.

---

For any locally compact group $G$ we can turn both $L^1(G)$ and $M(G)$ into Banach $*$-algebras, as you do.  Then we can consider $*$-representations on Hilbert spaces, say $\pi:L^1(G) \rightarrow B(H)$.  These are always norm-decreasing, so by taking a direct sum (say over all cyclic representations, so the sum is not too big) we can find a maximal $*$-representation, which induces a maximal $C^*$-algebra norm on $L^1(G)$.  The completion is $C^*(G)$ the group $C^*$-algebra.

$L^1(G)$ is an ideal in $M(G)$ (identified as the continuous measures with respect to the Haar measure) and in fact $M(G)$ is the *multiplier algebra* of $L^1(G)$.  Given any $\pi:L^1(G) \rightarrow B(H)$ we view $H$ as a left $L^1(G)$ module which is essential, as $\pi$ is non-degenerate.  By [Cohen-Hewitt Factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%E2%80%93Hewitt_factorization_theorem) every $\xi\in H$ is of the form $\pi(f)\eta$ for some $f\in L^1(G), \eta\in H$.  We can hence extend $\pi$ to $\tilde\pi:M(G)\rightarrow B(H)$ by defining $\tilde\pi(\mu) \xi = \tilde\pi(\mu)\pi(f)\eta = \pi(\mu \star f)\eta$.  This can be checked to be well-defined and to give a $*$-homomorphism.

---

When $G$ is abelian (more generally, amenable) there is no need to consider arbitrary $\pi$ but just the left-regular representation $\lambda:L^1(G)\rightarrow B(L^2(G))$, and so we identify $C^*(G)$ with $C^*_r(G)$ the reduced group $C^*$-algebra acting on $L^2(G)$.  The Fourier transform $\mathcal F:L^2(G) \rightarrow L^2(\hat G)$ intertwines $C^*_r(G)$ and the action of $C_0(\hat G)$, giving an isomorphism.

The Fourier transform $\mathcal F:L^1(G) \rightarrow C_0(\hat G)$ has image the *Fourier Algebra* $A(\hat G)$ which is dense in $C_0(\hat G)$.  This is compatible with the isomorphism between $C^*_r(G)$ and $C_0(\hat G)$.

We extend $\lambda$ to $M(G) \rightarrow B(L^2(G))$ which maps into the $C^*$-algebraic multiplier algebra $M(C^*_r(G))$.  The Fourier transform identifies $M(C^*_r(G))$ with $M(C_0(\hat G)) = C^b(\hat G)$ and is compatible with $\mathcal F:M(G)\rightarrow B(\hat G)\subseteq C^b(\hat G)$ where $B(\hat G)$ is the *Fourier-Stieljtes algebra*.

---

So you are interested in states on $M(G)$ which arise by integrating a $B(\hat G)$ function against a probability measure in $M(\hat G) = C_0(\hat G)^*$.  Un-winding the isomorphisms, these are the states on $M(G)$ which come from a state $\mu$ on $C^*(G)$.  We first extend $\mu$ to the multiplier algebra $M(C^*(G))$, then take our mapping $M(G) \rightarrow M(C^*(G))$, and then apply the extension of the state.

You hence ask: which states on $M(G)$ arise in this way?  This could be asked for any locally compact group.

The answer is: there must be a state $\mu$ on $L^1(G)$ whose canonical extension to the multiplier algebra $M(L^1(G)) = M(G)$ gives the state you started with.  To show this:

- If we start with a state on $C^*(G)$, then restrict to $L^1(G)$.  The extensions to the relevant multiplier algebras are the same.
- Conversely, if we have a state $\mu$ on $L^1(G)$ which extends to your state on $M(G)$ then we can perform the GNS construction to find $\pi:L^1(G)\rightarrow B(H)$ and $\xi\in H$ with $\mu(f) = (\xi|\pi(f)\xi)$ for each $f\in L^1(G)$.  Hence $\mu$ extends to $C^*(G)$.

---

So how do we detect when a state $\mu$ on $M(G)$ arises from the extension of a state on $L^1(G)$?  Let $(e_i)$ be a bounded approximate identity for $L^1(G)$.  Then the extension $\tilde\mu$ satisfies (or is defined by)
$$ \tilde\mu(\alpha) = \lim_i \mu(\alpha\star e_i) \qquad (\alpha\in M(G)). $$
As we want $\mu = \tilde\mu$, we need exactly that $\mu(\alpha) = \lim_i \mu(\alpha \star e_i)$ for each $\alpha\in M(G)$.

For example, your "bad" state $\mu:\alpha\mapsto\alpha(\{e\})$ actually annihilates $L^1(G)$, and so cannot be an extension of a state on $L^1(G)$.

**Conclusion:** You need to know not just $M(G)$ but also how $L^1(G)$ sits inside $M(G)$.

---

About extensions: let $A$ be a $C^*$-algebra, and let $\mu\in A^*$.  As $A^*$ is an *essential* $A$-module, by Cohen-Hewitt factorisation, there are $b\in A, \lambda\in A^*$ with $\mu=a\cdot\lambda$.  Then we may define $\tilde\mu:M(A)\rightarrow\mathbb C$ by $\tilde\mu(x) = \lambda(xa)$.  Let $(e_i)$ be a bounded approximate identity for $A$, so that for $x\in M(A)$ we have that $xa = \lim_i e_i x e_i a$ and so
$$ \tilde\mu(x) = \lambda(xa) = \lim_i \lambda(e_i x e_i a) = \lim_i \mu(e_i x e_i). $$
As we can choose $e_i$ self-adjoint, it follows that $\mu$ positive implies $\tilde\mu$ positive.  If $\mu$ is a state (meaning $\|\mu\|=1$ and $\mu$ is positive) then by the norm estimates we get from Cohen-Hewitt, also $\|\tilde\mu\|=1$ so $\tilde\mu$ is a state.

Comment: Matthew, this is very interesting, but this brings the problem into the area of relations between $M(G)$  and $L^1(G)$ (instead of the pairing  $M(G) \leftrightarrow C_0(G)$). Is there a possibility to restore $L^1(G)$ from $M(G)$? I mean, suppose we have an abstract Banach algebra with involution $A$, do we have a construction that converts $A$ into another algebra $B$ so that in the special case when $A=M(G)$ the algebra $B$ turns out to be $L^1(G)$?

Comment: @SergeiAkbarov For $G=\mathbb{R}$ (reals) it is possible to restore $L^1(G)$ from $M(G)$: It is the largest separable ideal in $M(G)$.

Comment: @user95282 excuse me, what does "separable ideal" mean?

Comment: @user95282 can you give a reference for this? I would read.

Comment: By "separable" I mean "separable in norm" --- it has a countable dense subset. A measure $\mu\in M(\mathbb{R})$ is in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ if and only if its principal ideal $M(\mathbb{R})\ast\mu$ is separable.

Comment: @user95282 ah, ok! However, I  need a reference. And you know, this sounds exotic from the point of view of categorical language. Do you happen to know other ways to obtain $L^1(G)$ from $M(G)$?

Comment: R. Larsen, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 19 (1968), 569--572, proves that if a measure on a second countable LC group has a separable orbit then it is absolutely continuous.

Comment: For another way of recognizing $L^1(G)$ inside $M(G)$, see B.E. Johnson, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 15 (1964), 186--188.

Comment: OK, thank you !

Comment: Matthew, excuse me, this detail -- "We first extend $\mu$ to the multiplier algebra $M(C^*(G))$" -- does it mean that  each state $\mu$  on an involutive Banach algebra $A$ is uniquely extended to the multiplier algebra $M(A)$?

Comment: If I understand the question, then "no".  This is a slightly special property of $C^*$-algebras (and some other Banach algebras): always the dual space $A^*$ is a (left) module over $A$, but for a $C^*$-algebra it is an essential module, and $A$ has a bounded approximate identity, so we can apply Cohen-Factorisation to see that each $\mu$ is of the form $a\cdot\lambda$, and then given $x\in M(A)$ we (well-)define $x\cdot\mu = xa\cdot\lambda$.

Comment: Matthew, I don't understand something, excuse me, this is far from me. We have a functional $\mu:A\to{\mathbb C}$, and we want to construct its extension, the functional $\widetilde{\mu}:M(A)\to{\mathbb C}$. We notice that $\mu=a\cdot\lambda$ for some $a\in A$ and $\lambda\in A^*$. Then (as far as I understand) we consider the mapping $x\in M(A)\mapsto x\cdot a\cdot \lambda\in A^*$. Where is the functional $\widetilde{\mu}:M(A)\to{\mathbb C}$?

Comment: Ah, sorry, a typo on my part.  You should have $\tilde\mu(x) = \lambda(xa)$.

Comment: Ah, OK, thank you!

Comment: Matthiew excuse me, in this science each step requires explanations for me. Now I don't understand why $\widetilde{\mu}$ is a state (or is positive).